# Github Action: Top level 'runs:' section is required

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I'm trying to create a github action that I can use inside my many projects that I'll be making in the future. Unfortunately I'm getting this github action error and I'm not sure how I can fix the problem.

I have created a repository for the github action and within it is a `action.yml` file:

```
name: flowcheck install dependencies & run code checkers
description: Install dependencies, run code checkers & run linter on creating and updating a Pull request.
branding:
  icon: 'check-circle'
  color: 'green'

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '8.1'

      - name: Install Composer dependencies
        run: composer install --no-progress --no-suggest

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16'

      - name: Install npm dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Run tests
        run: composer run test

      - name: Run linter
        run: npm run lint
```

Now I've tried publishing it to the github marketplace and then use it in one of my projects like:

```
name: Run flowcheck

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: flowcheck install dependencies & run code checkers
        uses: keygun-development/FlowCheck@v2.0.0
```

When the action ran it gave me an error: Github Action: Top level 'runs:' section is required for keygun-development/FlowCheck/v2.0.0/action.yml. I'm totally new to Github Actions (as you can see) and I need some help with the problem I'm facing.

How can I fix this problem? And please explain what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: It looks like you're mixing up reusable workflows and actions. What you have is closer to a [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows), though they need an `on: workflow_call` trigger. [Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions) don't have `on` triggers at all.

Comment: Have a look at the example metadata file in the docs for [composite actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action).

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for your help! The example you've provided is really helpful. I'm now using a `runs:` and `using: "composite"` and anywhere where a script needs to run I've added a `shell`. The job is now succeeding as expected.